# Python NotifyChangeEventLog (6, 'NotifyChangeEventLog', 'The handle is invalid.')

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32, event-log

This is my code:

```
    import win32evtlog
    import win32event
    
    SERVER = '192.168.1.221'  # IP of remote PC
    SOURCE_TYPE = 'System'
    
    def syslogHandler(host, source_type):
        h_log = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(host, source_type)
        h_evt0 = win32event.CreateEvent(None, True, False, 'evt0')
        win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog(h_log, h_evt0)
    
    syslogHandler(SERVER, SOURCE_TYPE)
```

It works perfectly fine with `localhost`, but whenever I try to run this script with other pc IP (e.g '192.168.1.221') it returns

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:\Programming\PyCharm_projects\Test\main.py", line 14, in 
            syslogHandler(SERVER, SOURCE_TYPE)
        File "D:\Programming\PyCharm_projects\Test\main.py", line 11, in syslogHandler
            win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog(h_log, h_evt0)
    pywintypes.error: (6, 'NotifyChangeEventLog', 'The handle is invalid.')
```

Without line `win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog(h_log, h_evt0)` script works perfectly fine.

I can add `events = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(h_log, win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ | win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ, 0)` and it returns all events from remote PC.

Both computers are members of domain. Remote PC in this example is Windows Server 2016. Script is run by user with admin privilages(on both local and domain PCs).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for remote systems, which makes sense (as if it was, a machine's event log could be easily spammed (by a privileged user from another machine)).

According to [[MS.Docs]: NotifyChangeEventLog function (winbase.h) - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-notifychangeeventlog#remarks) (***emphasis*** is mine):

> The **NotifyChangeEventLog** function ***does not work with remote handles***. If the *hEventLog* parameter is the handle to an event log on a remote computer, **NotifyChangeEventLog** returns zero, and [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) returns **ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE**.